# Some of my python package can't be installed with the "$conda ... " command

Tags: python, bash, batch-file, pip, conda

Our software in python has about 5 dependencies. This year, to help the new students joining our project, we wish to create an installer that will fetch all the dependencies by the classic requirements.txt file method. 
I then wish to make both a batch and bash script that will go over requirements.txt and install the dependencies.

Right now I've managed to write scripts that will either do `conda install ...` or `pip3 install ...` but as **two separate command files**. Considering which package manager to choose I want as much freedom as can be, so I am left wondering if there is a way to have the console use conda by **default** and if it fails use pip3?
 *For example : I haven't manage to install pyqt5 with conda but succeeded with pip3.*

Here's my batch script:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (requirements.txt) do (conda install --yes %%A)
pause
```

Here's the bash script :

```
while read requirement; do conda install --yes $requirement; done < requirements.txt
```

And lastly my requirements.txt content:

```
pySerial
pyQt5
pyopenGL
pyproj
pyqtgraph
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In batch, you can use `action_a || action_b` to perform action_b if action_a fails. For your script, that would be

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (requirements.txt) do (conda install --yes %%A || pipe %%A)
```

Bash has a similar feature.

```
while read requirement; do conda install --yes $requirement || pip3 $requirement; done < requirements.txt
```

(note that I'm not sure about `pip3`'s syntax, so change it accordingly)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, had to change the syntax a bit like you suggested for pip3 and now it seems to be working just fine!